# Docker-compose to configmap conversion

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a docker compose file and tried to create deployment and service from that. But when it comes to the configmap i have some issue in the setting the logs to configmap

```
volumes:
    - ./configuration/project-db:/usr/projects/project-db:z,ro
    - logs:${LOG_PATH}
```

Can anyone tell me how should i create a configmap for the logs specified in the volumes section

Comment: Thank you @Sanu Khan , I have created confimap for many of the application for mapping the configuration. The thing i don't understand from your command is the logs.txt which is not there on the application folder provided

Comment: logs.txt refers to the env file that you used in mapping attributes

Comment: Is this intended to be a place you write out application logs?  ConfigMaps are read-only and you can't write things there.  If you can configure the application to write its logs to stdout and remove this mount entirely, that's the easiest thing; otherwise I might use an `emptyDir` container-temporary volume.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
volumes:
  - ./configuration/project-db:/usr/projects/project-db:z,ro
  - logs:/path/to/logs
...
volumeMounts:
  - name: logs
    mountPath: ${LOG_PATH}
    readOnly: true
...
volumes:
  - name: logs
    configMap:
      name: logs-config
```

assuming you created a configMap
`kubectl create configmap logs-config --from-file=logs.txt`

Comment: How will create a configmap when there is no physical file exist

Comment: You can create configMap `kubectl create configmap logs-config`
once you created you may need to modify the configMap with attributes and apply the same to the cluster